# Rails - Generating a new Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If I have two models like this:

PhotoAlbums (id, creator_id)

Photos (photo_album_id, name)

In the PhotoAlbums controller, when I put a Belongs_to user in there, is there some way to tell Rails that the user is creator_id ?

Thanks

Comment: Is `creator_id` coming from some form of login/user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => :creator_id`

Just to be clear, you would call the `belongs_to` association method in your PhotoAlbums model, not the controller (i.e., `models/photo_album.rb`).

Take a look at the following API Documentation for more information on how to override the conventions that Rails uses for the `belongs_to` method. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to

Comment: Thank you.. But, when you have two related models like this.. A photoalbum is automatically created when you upload one or more photos. So should I be using the photo controller/views to create the records or the photoalbums?

Comment: So are photos uploaded before a photo album exists?

Comment: It happens at the same time. when a photo is uploaded rails will find or create an album based on a random UID.

Comment: Because I detect that you're a bit new to Rails, let me just say this first: Whether to put your logic in the Photos or PhotoAlbums controller is a design decision that is completely up to you. Best way to go about it is to ask yourself: Does this logic belong to a particular controller? If it does, then put the logic there. Not knowing much about your application, I can't give a definite answer. In this case, it seems like the logic could belong to the Photos controller. However, I would even be inclined to create an UploadController to handle this operation instead.

Comment: Thanks John, appreciate the explanation.